# Using View Binding in Widget android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-viewbinding

I am using Widget for my Android application .
I need to know how can I apply view binding concept for RemoteViews in widget

Code :

```
 // Construct the RemoteViews object.
    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.name_of_layout)
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewWidgetId, appWidgetId.toString())
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_update, context.resources.getString(R.string.date_count_format, count, dateString))
```

Comment: I do not believe that there is a view binding equivalent for `RemoteViews`, sorry.